# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable when saving to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pickle

I want to save a dataframe (downloaded data from internet, picked and then unpickled) to local csv file, but always getting errors on accessing it. See attached code.

[see my code as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu9L8.png)

Comment: paste your relevant code here.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code in the question.

Comment: Also paste your error message

Comment: import pickle
from yahoo_historical import Fetcher
import csv

date_fm = [2017,7,1]
date_to = [2017,9,25]
share = 'UCG.MI'

def loadDownloader(share, date_fm, date_to):
    data = Fetcher(share, date_fm, date_to)
    return(data.getHistorical())

def saveDownloader(downloader, share, date_fm, date_to):
    with open(share+str(date_fm)+str(date_to) + ".pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(downloader, file=f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

Comment: sorry but where can I attach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to try and manually write your CSV file using the `csv` library as you already have `saved` in a Pandas Dataframe format. To save this to CSV is a simple as just adding:

```
saved.to_csv('{}{}{}.csv'.format(share, date_fm, date_to))
```

For example:

```
import pickle
from yahoo_historical import Fetcher
import csv

def loadDownloader(share, date_fm, date_to):
    data = Fetcher(share, date_fm, date_to)
    return(data.getHistorical())

def saveDownloader(downloader, share, date_fm, date_to):
    with open('{}{}{}.pickle'.format(share, date_fm, date_to), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(downloader, file=f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def main():
    downloader = None
    share = str(input('share, eg. "UCG.MI" : '))
    y_fm = int(input('start date Year : '))
    m_fm = int(input('start date Month : '))
    d_fm = int(input('start date Day : '))
    y_to = int(input('end date Year : '))
    m_to = int(input('end date Month : '))
    d_to = int(input('end date Day : '))

    date_fm = [y_fm, m_fm, d_fm]
    date_to = [y_to, m_to, d_to]
    print("Retrieving data")
    downloader = loadDownloader(share, date_fm, date_to)
    saveDownloader(downloader,share, date_fm, date_to)

    with open('{}{}{}.pickle'.format(share, date_fm, date_to), 'rb') as f:
        saved = pickle.load(f)

    print("Exporting in progress")
    saved.to_csv('{}{}{}.csv'.format(share, date_fm, date_to))
    print("Job done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also note the use of `format()` to make your string formatting easier.

This would give you a CSV output file looking like:

[image: Excel screenshot]

If you still wanted to do it manually:

```
with open('{}{}{}.csv'.format(share, date_fm, date_to), 'w', newline='') as fileobj:
    newFile = csv.writer(fileobj)
    newFile.writerow(saved.columns.values)   # Get header names

    for index, row in saved.iterrows():
        newFile.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much Martin &all

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to select an answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is obviously in the line of code:

```
for row in saved():
```

The brackets after saved are causing an issue because it is not a callable object.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7eba056c7420> in <module>()
     29     print("Job done")
     30 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 31     main()

<ipython-input-3-7eba056c7420> in main()
     26         newFile = csv.writer(fileobj)
     27         for row in saved:
---> 28             newFile.writerow(row)
     29     print("Job done")
     30 if __name__ == "__main__":

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'